# calling web service using POST to retrieve data using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, web-services

i have a task to call we service using c# and ASP and all i have in this task is a **LINK** and it's not .asmx or wsdl , it's a normal link like https://www.normallink.com

i tried this link using Postman extension and it brought a json data with POST method so how can i retrieve these data using ASP

this is example of json data from Postman

```
 "data": [
    {
        "id": "516",
        "name": "xyz"
    },
```

Comment: You could try to google "c# call web service using POST" and look at the thousands of examples available online

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
String jsonData = ...; 

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.mywebservice.com/");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";

using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter postWriter = new StreamWriter(postStream))
        postWriter.Write(jsonData);
}

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
String responseContent;

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
       responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply....but it's not working please can you give me more explanation ?

Comment: Well "it's not working is a bit too generic" if you want some hint, you have to tell me more about this...